# I can't find Web element with xpath using driver.findElement(By.xpath());

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find the link on a page to click:

```
<a id="folder0" class="js-folder icon-wrap icon-wrap_left menu__item__link menu__item__link_act menu__item__link_unread" href="/messages/inbox" rel="history">
    <span class="js-folder-b-unread js-folder-unread menu__item__link__qnt">7</span>
    <i class="js-folder-ico icon icon_left icon_folders icon_inbox_act"></i>
    <span class="menu__item__link__text menu__item__link__text_linear">Input</span>
</a>
```

Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='folder0']/span[2]")).click();
```

But the driver can't locate the element:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='folder0']/span[2]"}
```

Comment: Are there any other elements in the DOM with `id="folder0"`? Id's are meant to be unique, so your xpath will look for a 2nd span relative to the FIRST `id="folder0"` it finds, and then stop looking.

Comment: @Pat Meeker .This is unique element in the DOM.I understand what do you mean about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for all answers. I found solution to my problem. The last command was command which was linked with IFrame

```
WebElement editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sentmsgcomposeEditor_ifr"));
   driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame);

   WebElement body1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
   body1.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
```

So i was in IFrame actually because of it i couldn't find any element.
I performed following command:

```
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

After that it is possible to find locators.

Comment: Any specific reason why this extra step is required? Because anyway, the element is in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to locate by id instead of by xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("folder0")).click();
```

Two reasons:

1. Locating by id is usually faster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777694/which-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-find-the-element-using-webdriver-by-xpath) for why).
2. Since you're trying to test the link, you don't need to click on an inner `<span>`, just on the link element itself.

**If you still want to use xpath**, or still want to get the inner `<span>`, you can use firebug in Firefox to copy the xpath; this will give you the correct xpath and show you if you made a mistake.
[image: Firebug Copying XPath]

Comment: Thank you for verbose explanation.
1) I can't find element by Id
I had such message: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"folder0"}

Comment: 2)I use Firebug and Xpath to find locator i need .

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the `.`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='folder0']/span[2]")).click();
```

Comment: @BilowYuriy Although I still like my solution better, this answer actually tells you why what you were trying didn't work.

Comment: @Pat Meeker I tried
        'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='folder0']/span[2]")).click();'
and had 
         org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='folder0']/span[2]"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.05 seconds