# Comparison of By.id, By.className and By.xpath given only a highlevel parent-id and a className of a child

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Disclaimer:** I went through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777694/which-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-find-the-element-using-webdriver-by-xpath). But would like more insight on situations similar to the code below.

```
<div id="feedback-filter-buttons" class="ui-buttonset">
    <label class="filter-label ui-button ui-corner-top" for="feedback-all" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text">Very Good</span>
    </label>
    <label class="ui-button" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text"><span > Good </span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="ui-button" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text"><span > Alright </span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="ui-button ui-state-active" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text"><span > Bad</span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="ui-button" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text"><span > Very Bad</span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="ui-button ui-corner-bottom" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text"><span > Undefined (0)</span></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Objective:** 
To get the text of the currently selected (ie., active) label(button).

**Approaches:** 
a) `webDriver.findElement(By.id("feedback-filter-buttons")).findElement(By.className("ui-state-active")).getText()`

b) `webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='feedback-filter-buttons']/label[contains(@class,'ui-state-active')]/span")).getText()`

**Question:**
Which of the above approaches is better and why? At the moment, I am leaning towards xpath as I am able to specify the path till the final element I require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the performance point of view, the `xpath` approach would be slower and I'd go with the first option.

For starters, you use `*` (not specifying the actual tag), which makes it traverse the tree, do a full page scan; and then you apply `contains()`, which is a string matching function.

Searching `By.id()` is definitely the fastest approach, since under-the-hood it is calling `getElementById()` which browsers know how to optimize. Plus, you are quickly narrowing down the search scope to the parent element and then make a search inside by the class name.

Besides, relying on these `id` and `class` attributes is not only making your testing code readable and easily understandable, but also more explicit and robust. Think about possible errors: in case of `xpath` approach, you would only get that it cannot find the element using the xpath you gave it - not really informative, you would not even know where to start debugging. In case of `id+class` approach, you would see two different kinds of errors: "could not find the parent by id" and "could not find the element by class name".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Also how does find `By.className` fare compared with `id` and `xpath`? Additionally I am dealing with many lists of items where the item(assume a case where class `'ui-state-active'` is absent) dom structure remains the same but the item div index changes. Eg: A sample code: `"//div[@id='d-view']/div[3]/div["+index+"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]"` within a for loop. Would you recommend accessing such an item `By.xpath` as above or a `By.cssSelector`? I could ask a separate question if you want me to.

Comment: @Siva well, I would not recommend relying on the element position inside it's parent too much and often. Having xpath expressions like `... div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]` is usually a sign of a very fragile one. Usually there are certain things/anchors you can rely on isntead. `xpath` or `css selector` - I suppose the speed heavily depends on the driver/browser. You can also have other reasons to use either this or that depending on the required functionality, simplicity etc. Yeah, this can probably be a part of a separate interesting topic. Thanks.