# Vairance in script execution using webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My problem is a bit generic one, so please bear with me.

I'm using

-selenium 2.44/eclipse Kepler/Java 1.7_071/JXL API/ Internet Explorer Driver Server 2.44

My OS is Windows 7 & IE version 9

Execution speed of my script varies a lot machine to machine.I have used xpath/ID/linkText/className for element identification, Even the element identified with linkText responds too slow.
. I have used webdriver wait like this

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).ignoring(Exception.class).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(Location)));
```

Can somebody tell me what could be the factors affecting the execution speed & how to improve it.

Note:- The application under test works fine manually.

Comment: Have you tried only with `new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(Location)));` /

Comment: @Saifur Yes, This has been all over my code & its not that it doesn't work,infact it has worked perfectly on some machines

Comment: No. I am asking if you have tried without the `ignoring` to test the speed

Comment: @Saifur it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue!

I think you are using 64 bit IE driverserver. Use 32 bit driverserver instead of 64 bit. You will see some improvement.

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.44/

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- As @vinoth S says there is a known issue with IE 64x bit driver. To proof this I actually did a bench marking yesterday. This is how it looks. I had a simple login and logout script which ran 10 times So change your driver to 32x if so.

[image]

- Use id everywhere if possible and possibly css selector over xpath. Avoid linktext, partial linktext as much as you can.
  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777694/which-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-find-the-element-using-webdriver-by-xpath)