# Capture non-unique/dynamic objects in Pega using Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, pega

We are facing lots of problem to capturing objects using developer tool because of IFrame / Frame, all objects mapping with more than one IFrame and Frame.

Kindly let me know Selenium webdriver is suitable for automating PEGA application?

Comment: What version of pega do you have?

Comment: Pega 7 (7.1.8 to be exact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Live UI and find out the Test ID (data-test-id) element in most of the HTML input field tags

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your Pega application was implemented. If you look for example on the default Case Worker portal you can see there is no single IFrame in there.

It is true that the developer portal has Iframes, but why would you test the developer tool?

You can also read: [Which is the best and fastest way to find the element using webdriver? By.XPath or By.ID or anything else? And why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777694/which-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-find-the-element-using-webdriver-by-xpath). Maybe looking for elements by ID is more suitable for you.