# Need to click on sub option of dropdown menu in OWA

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation, outlook-web-app

My test script are developed using Java with Selenium webdriver api. There is 1 particular scenario where I need to click on a sub option loaded from a dropdown menu but I am not able to do that. Following are the test steps and the screenshot for the particular problem.

-Launch Microsoft Outlook Web App (OWA) and login

-On main screen I need to enter some text in Search Field

-Click the drop down next to it

-Select "**This Folder**" from the options loaded
([Screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/2rh5rwg/9))

I dont see any frameid so not using any. Dropdown works fine but failing to click on suboption.

Adding the code which I am using for click this

```
public static final By searchDropDown_locator= By.xpath(".//*[@id='divSScp']");
public static final By thisFolderText_locator= By.xpath("(.//*[@id='spnT' and text()='This Folder'])[2]");


public void clickSearchDropDown()
{
    WebElement searchIcon= websitedriver.findElement(searchDropDown_locator);
    searchIcon.click(); 
}

public void clickThisFolder()
{
    WebElement searchIcon= websitedriver.findElement(thisFolderText_locator);
    searchIcon.click(); 
}
```

I am calling both these functions in my script file.

What could be the solution here.

Comment: @lrf - This question is much tougher to answer when you don't post the code that you have.

Comment: @lrf - Is `XPath` your only option for finding the 'This Folder' selector?

Comment: @Brian Yes. We are using xpath to identify the screen elements. What other option you are suggesting.

Comment: @lrf - Well, there are quite a few to choose from like, `name`, `className`, `id`, `cssSelector`.  Finding by `XPath` can be unreliable and cumbersome.  Do you have the option to use one of the others I suggested?

Comment: @Brian In current situation I would try other options till I get solution with xpath.

Comment: @lrf - See, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777694/which-is-the-best-and-fastest-way-to-find-the-element-using-webdriver-by-xpath).

Comment: @Brian Finding xpath is not a problem, I have the correct xpath for this element. The problem is, it is not clicking. Something I am not doing correctly which I want to find. I tried using id but same result it is failing to click.

Comment: @lrf - Try:  `WebElement searchIcon= websitedriver.findElement(thisFolderText_locator).click();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JavascriptExecutor for click as below

```
public void clickSearchDropDown()
{
    WebElement searchIcon= websitedriver.findElement(searchDropDown_locator);
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", searchIcon);
}

public void clickThisFolder()
{
    WebElement searchIcon= websitedriver.findElement(thisFolderText_locator);
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", searchIcon);
}
```

Hope it will help you :)