# Is it a bad idea to use locator names in templates to write easier E2E tests?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, protractor

I am finding it really hard to locate stuff I am testing when its deep nested, etc.

Is it a bad idea to use something

```
<h1 name="test-main-title">About Us</h1>
```

and just use

```
element(by.name('test-main-title'));?
```

Later, for the prod build, I can remove `name="test-*"` from my HTML files.  Just want to knwo if that is a terrible idea before I start doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea itself is similar to modifying application or a specific application build for testing or staging to make the testing easier. The idea itself is quite common and has its pros and cons. I don't though particularly like the idea of changing existing attribute values for that. Instead, think about adding meaningful `id`s and data-oriented `class`es or other attributes.

`id`s specifically have multiple advantages - they are less likely to be changed, they are unique (at least they should in theory), they are data-oriented (meaning, you probably would not have an id equal to `col-sm-6`) and they are the fastest way to locate elements.

Also, here are the related threads with more ideas:

- [Test automation html element selectors. Element ID or DataAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492803/test-automation-html-element-selectors-element-id-or-dataattribute)
- [Is adding IDs to everything standard practice when using Selenium?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6326/is-adding-ids-to-everything-standard-practice-when-using-selenium)

Comment: thank you!  I think I will keep using name (or should I use id?  does it matter?)   because I think it will be easier for me.

Comment: @user1354934 yeah, sorry for multiple edits - I should probably kill that perfectionist inside me always complaining smth is not good enough.

Comment: may i ask one more question?  so what exactly should I be testing with protractor?  i'm trying to learn all this stuff.  Is it mostly for where you have data, or for all kinds of stuff?  sorry if its to general a question :(  for example i wrote a test to make sure i am on the right url, that the h1 title is correct, and that the button that's part of a card my repeater renders reads "add"

Comment: @user1354934 sure. Well, this is difficult to answer cause there is no silver bullet and it is application-under-test specific. If you don't have any tests at this point I suggest focusing on the most critical parts of the application first, or things that are most likely to break, or where the "money" is :)

Comment: ah i see.  thanks!  wasn't too sure from the documentation what exactly i am suppose to test.

Comment: ID are unique not only in theory: also in practice. As in: if ID is not unique, locating element by non-unique ID fails. That allows it to be so fast.